# How to click in every element have this class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

How to click in every element have this class one by one

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[role="menuitemradio"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *`for()`* loop to iterate through the elements as follows:

```
for ele in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[role="menuitemradio"]'):
    ele.click()
```